# How to sort even and odd numbers alternatively with the limit of time and space complexity?(C/C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Given a `integer array` like

```
int numbers[8]={1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 2};
```

The half side in the front array are odd numbers, and the rest (the equal amount number) 
are even. The odd numbers are in an ascending order and even part are in a descending order. After the sorting, the order of the numbers can't be changed.

How can I sort them alternatively with time complexity **less** than `O(n^2)` and space complexity `O(1)`?

For this example, the result would be: `{1,8,3,6,5,4,7,2}`;

**I can't use external array storage but temporary variables are acceptable.**

I have tried to use two pointers(`oddPtr, evenPtr`) to point odd and even numbers separately, and move `evenPtr`to insert the even values to the middles of odd numbers.(Like insertion sort)
But it takes `O(n^2)`.

**UPDATED**

Comment: plain quicksort as implemented by `std::sort`

Comment: The time complexity of quciksort is O(n ^2).

Comment: @Stallman std::sort has complexity of `O(n*log(n))` it uses introsort - a combination of quickosrt with several other algorithms. quicksort complexity is O(n^2) in the **worst case**.

Comment: But it requires me to avoid O(n ^ 2) even in the worst case.

Comment: Also quicksort is generally put in the same category as O(nlogn) algorithms because in practice that's how it acts. The worst case is extremely rare. But if you insist, you can write an in-place merge sort as well. (Introsort is quicksort with a heapsort backup if the recursion goes too deep)

Comment: This link may have a solution. http://www.careercup.com/question?id=7528760

Comment: Oh my GOD, it's too simple but a little tricky... Why am I too stupid to know that?! Thank you, Abhishek Bansal!, although it's too late...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Dukeling's comment I realized that the solution I propose in fact is not linear,but linearithmic and even worse - you can't control if it takes extra memory or not. On my second thought I realized you know a lot about the array you to implement a more specific, but probably easier solution.

I will make an assumption that all values in the array are positive. I need this so that I can use negative values as kind of 'already processed' flag. My idea is the following - iterate over the array from left to right. For each element if it is already processed(i.e. its value is negative) simply continue with the next one. Otherwise you will have a constant formula where is the position where this element should be:

- If the value is odd and its index is `i` it should move to `i*2`
- If the value is even and its index is `i` it should move to `(i - n/2)*2 + 1`

Store this value into a temporary and make the value at the current index of the array 0. Now until the position where the value we 'have at hand' is not zero, swap it with the value staying at the position we should place it according to the formula above. Also when you place the value at hand negate it to 'mark it as processed'. Now we have a new value 'at hand' and again we calculate where it should go according to the formula above. We continue moving values until the value we 'have at hand' should go to the position with 0. With a little thought you can prove that you will never have a negative('processed') value at hand and that eventually you will end up at the empty spot of the array.

After you process all the values iterate once over the array to negate all values and you will have the array you need. The complexity of the algorithm I describe is linear- each value will be no more than once 'at hand' and you will iterate over it no more than once.

Comment: +1, but I wonder now if `inplace_merge` would work, given that the ranges are ordered according to different criteria.

Comment: How in-place merge can work? I can't split the origin array to 2 parts since it requires additional memory.

Comment: @Stallman you have to implement your own comparator of integer with an alternative implementation of the comparison `operator <`. You  don't need to split the array, you only have to find the position at which the even numbers start. Read `inplace_merge` documentation, please.

Comment: Actually, since you only have constant extra space, it's linearithmic (as per the link you provided). I see this more as an algorithm question, i.e. "use this library function" is not a particularly good answer, unless you also explain how the function works.

Comment: @Dukeling your note is absolutely correct. I have changed my answer completely and now I believe it meets OP's needs. Plus that I learned a new thing - I always thought inplace merge is linear in all cases.

Comment: Well... Please give me some days(I need to be abroad.) to consider your solution is right or not. Actually the answer is right here:  careercup.com/question?id=7528760 (Abhishek Bansal mentioned that).
Thank you for your help!

Comment: +1. Instead of assuming all the values are positive, why not make use of the existing redundancy in the parity:  convert all values to even (e.g., by exclusive or with 1, or simply negating all the bits), and convert them to odd as they're processed.  At the finish, convert every other value back to even.